# Eclipse conditional breakpoint, break at any string equals

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I have a large (legacy) application that I have to make a fix in, with terrible code structure and so much code smell that I'm choking. I can't really figure out where a string in the gui is populated. Therefore it would be nice if i somehow could have an expression/breakpoint once ANY string (I don't know the name of the variable, or where it is) is equal to "foobar" so I can backtrack from there.

So, what am I looking for? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt something like "break whenever any String equals X" exists, but is the text somehow obtained from a file or database? Besides, which kind of UI to you use, maybe we can help with the methods of UI populating.

Comment: @Smutje The UI is built on a home-made framework that is built from scope framework, so that makes it really hard. The problem is that a lot of the communication and access is obfuscated and abstracted and entangled in this home-made framework. So there are like a gazillion layers to keep track of. Also, i'm interested in general, since it would be a nice feature to have some times when looking for something in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trick works as long as the string that you want to find isn't hard-coded in any way. If the string was getting passed to the compiler, then this trick may not work.

1. Ensure you have installed the source-code alongside the JDK.
2. Open `java.lang.String` class file. Your IDE should be automatically show the source-code for this class.
3. Put a breakpoint in the `char[]` field variable. The variable name may vary for each JDK. On my machine it is `private final char value[];`.
4. Put a condition on this breakpoint, e.g.:

   ```
   value!=null && value.length==6 && value[0]=='f' && value[1]=='o' && value[2]=='o' ....
   ```

Please note that the performance will be slower due to this breakpoint.

I have tested this on a simple application that read the string from a file, and the breakpoint is being hit properly when the file is being read into a string.

Comment: I'm not able to verify this, but it sounds very promising!

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t know where the String gets populated, but you do know where the variable it is in is, you can place a watchpoint for the variable.
A watchpoint is exactly placed as a breakpoint, but in the line where the variable is defined.

This watchpoint will pause the programm everytime the variable is changed or read.

Comment: as mentioned, "(I don't know the name of the variable, or where it is)"

Comment: He meant to watch the source of the String not the variable it gets placed into.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have an IDE, such as Eclipse, you can set getters and setters for all your variables then, from every one of these setters, call a function called "checkValue" for example, in this "checkValue" make a conditional breakpoint for the specific value you are looking for.

This will require code to be changed, but as a by-product, would create a cleaner code.

---

Use jmap and cause memory dumps. Inspect every dump for the value you are looking for

---

Use Introspection and cycle through every variable, looking for the value.

Comment: 1. "Use getters and setters for all variables". That is just unreasonable, that is a LOT of code to change, just to break out the variables in order to do getters and setters. And also it's not cleaner to have getters and setters for local variables.

2. Will the memory dump tell me what the variable is called?

3. "Every variable", once again hard to do.

Comment: I didn't say any of them were easy ;). I'll keep checking the answers to see if anyone has better ideas. It would be nice to have a breakpoint based on value.